# Suspend process without killing it

Tags: process, kill

So I've got a persistent program running in the background. Killing it just causes it to restart with a different PID. I'd like to suspend it (put it to sleep without actually killing it). Does kill -9 do this? If not, how should this be done?

Answer (score 16):

```
kill -STOP $PID
[...]
kill -CONT $PID
```

*@jordanm* adds: Also note that like `SIGKILL` (same as `kill -9`) and `SIGSTOP` can **not** be ignored.

Answer (score 6):

*(Also to answer duplicate/closed question [How can I pause or freeze a running process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270761/how-can-i-pause-or-freeze-a-running-process), asking about what to do when applications crash after resume.)*

There are processes which do not resume properly after `kill -STOP $PID` & `kill -CONT $PID`. If that is the case you can try checkpoint/restore with [CRIU](http://criu.org/Main_Page). If you do not mind the overhead you can also run the process in a virtual machine, which you can suspend.

One reason why a process does not resume after `SIGSTOP`/`SIGCONT` could be that some blocking system calls on Linux fail with `EINTR` when the process is stopped and then resumed via `SIGCONT`. From **signal(7)**:

> **Interruption of system calls and library functions by stop signals**
>
> On  Linux,  even  in the absence of signal handlers, certain blocking
> interfaces can fail with the error EINTR after the process is stopped by
> one of the stop signals and then resumed via SIGCONT.  This  behavior  is
> not sanctioned by POSIX.1, and doesn't occur on other systems.
>
> [...]

One of the affected system calls is **epoll_wait(2)**. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd = 0;

    int efd = epoll_create(1);
    if (efd == -1) {
        perror("epoll_create");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct epoll_event ev;
    memset(&ev, 0, sizeof(ev));
    ev.events = EPOLLIN;
    ev.data.fd = fd;

    if (epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &ev) == -1) {
        perror("epoll_ctl");
        exit(1);
    }

    int res = epoll_wait(efd, &ev, 1, -1);
    if (res == -1) {
        perror("epoll_wait");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (ev.events & EPOLLIN && ev.data.fd == fd) {
        printf("Received input\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc -o example example.c
$ echo 'input' | ./example
Received input
$ ./example
Ctrl+Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./example
$ fg
./example
epoll_wait: Interrupted system call
```

Comment: >  and then resumed via SIGCONT < it says that system call gets `EINTR` when `SIGCONT` sent to stopped process. The program remains stopped until `SIGCONT` is sent

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pkill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkill) to send the `STOP` and `CONT` [signals](/questions/tagged/signals) signals to process-names, so that you don't need to find out the PID.

To suspend a process by name:

```
 pkill --signal STOP ProcessNameToSuspend
```

To wake that process back up:

```
 pkill --signal CONT ProcessNameToSuspend
```

On standard systems you have <kbd>TAB</kbd>-completion for the `ProcessName`, as well as for all other command elements.