# How can I pause or freeze a running process?

Tags: linux, process

I would like to pause/freeze a process in time; how can I do that?

Not duplicate because `kill -STOP <PID>` has caused applications to crash when I've used it.

Comment: You want to pause and freeze, I don't see the link to duplicating the process and how would you do that with `kill`? Did something get accidentally deleted when editing your post?

Comment: `STOP` is the canonical signal for this. What does "seems to be hit or miss" mean?

Comment: `kill -STOP` is the answer. If it causes some application to crash, that's a bug in the application, and we can't help you if you don't tell us what the application is (but the author of the application would be able to help you more).

Comment: Press Ctrl+Z if it's your foreground jobs (Equivalent to killing the foreground process group with SIGTSTP. SIGSTOP suspends unconditionally. SIGTSTP gives the process a chance to react.)

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `STOP` signal to pause a process, and `CONT` to resume its execution:

```
kill -STOP ${PID}
kill -CONT ${PID}
```

Comment: What is if the *process* to be frozen is not a mere trivial program, but one that interacts with lots of other processes? Will this form of freezing a process work then also?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace `kill -STOP` will pause a process regardless of what it’s doing or how complex it is; like `-KILL`, it can’t be overridden.

Comment: I want to pause the whole that is `gnome-session` a process that interdepents of/to/with other processes, I would expect that a pause->unpause would corrupt that intricate interplay of IPCs going on and hence be impractical, correct?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace yes, it would at least introduce delays (and presumably timeouts). I wouldn’t try it ;-).